# Splitting contents of a GitHub repository into branches

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository that currently only uses the master branch. There are two main directories; "chrome", and "android", for the Chrome app and Android app, respectively. I'd like to move everything inside the "android" directory to a new "chrome" branch, and move everything inside the "android" directory into a new "android" branch. I already have loads of history on all of the files and would like to keep that history in the new branch.

How do I go about doing this?
The repo I'm talking about: https://github.com/Gawdl3y/task-timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your branches, like this:

```
git branch chrome
git branch android
```

then, one by one, manipulate the branches

```
git checkout chrome
rm -r android/
git commit -a
git checkout android
rm -r chrome
git commit -a
```

and so on. Even moving files should keep history. good luck!

Comment: Won't this make GitHub think they're the same codebase, even though the Chrome branch would be radically different from the Android branch?

Comment: They would be the same project under github, but different branches. You could do the same, making them different projects, by doing a `git clone`, and then pushing to a seperate github project.

Answer (score 2):

If the two folders contain distinct code development, it may be prudent to separate the folders into two separate repositories. This can be done as follows:

1. Copy the entire project folder
2. `cd` into project copy
3. `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter <folder-name>`

The history will be retained for the specified folder's files and a repositories with all commits will now be in the root of the "new" versioned project folder.

***Note**: Where  is your "chrome" or "android" directory*

Comment: When you use the word repository, do you actually mean an entirely separate Git repository, or orphan branches?

Comment: I actually decided to separate them into their own repositories, like you suggested. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I marked the other answer as accepted, though, since it's the one answering my original question.